# Getting value from the <th> tag

Tags: python, html, parsing

How can I read the value from

```
<th class="class_name"> Sample Text </th>
```

Can any one help me in getting the string "Sample Text" from the above HTML code using python.

Thank you.

Comment: do you want parse whole xml file or only one string? if second one i think you could use regexp.

Comment: @ZagorulkinDmitry : I just need to get the "Sample Text" string. How can I use the regular expression here.?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) which is my favorite lib for parsing html.

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
html = '<th class="class_name"> Sample Text </th>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
print soup.th.text
```

Comment: Any particular reason you're not using `bs4` ?

Comment: `bs4` doesn't work (as well as it should). When trying, I got an `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'`. When doing `BeautifulSoup(html)`, it returned `<html><head></head><body> Sample Text </body></html>`

Comment: @Haidro Interesting - I get `<html><body><th class="class_name"> Sample Text </th></body></html>` - using bs4 - version 4.1.3

Comment: @Jon Clements Huh, I was going to post an answer with bs4 but when this appeared I didn't. How can I check what version I'm using?

Comment: @Haidro `import bs4; print bs4.__version__`

Comment: @JonClements 4.1.3 is returned. Weird. I used the exact same code as luc provided but changed from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup to from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25338/discussion-between-haidro-and-jon-clements)

Comment: bs4 may be a better choice. I didn't use it because it was not installed on the python I used for testing the code. So i was not sure that the behavior was the same.

Answer (score 0):

Regex solution:

```
import re

th_regex = re.compile(r'<th\s+class="class_name">(.*?)</th>')
search_result = th_regex.search(input_string)

print(search_result and search_result.group(1) or 'not found')
```

Note: you need to use `?` after `.*` to use non greedy search that will stop taking characters when `</th>` is occured. Otherwise you will get the whole string to the end of `input_string`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `minidom` to parse it.  I'm not sure what your exact needs are, though.

```
from xml.dom import minidom
dom = minidom.parseString(html)
for elem in dom.getElementsByTagName('th'):
    if elem.getAttribute('class') == 'class_name':
        print elem.firstChild.nodeValue
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex solution:

```
import re

s = '<th class="class_name"> Sample Text </th>'
data = re.findall('<th class="class_name">(.*?)</th>', s)
print data
```

Comment: Shouldn't `(.*)` be non-greedy? eg: `(.*?)`